# how to get a value out of ValuesQuerySet

Tags: python, django, dictionary, typeerror

I'm trying to extract some data from my database in my Django app with the following line of code.  Job is the name of my model and jobIDs[i] represents the id of the record being operated on.

```
timeToRun = Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i]).values()['whenToRun'].split(' ')[0]
```

When I get to ['whenToRun'] I get a TypeError().  Am I misunderstanding how to access values in this kind of dict?

EDIT: To clarify, .values() return a ValuesQuerySet

Comment: perhaps you have misspelled `filter` by `get`, second one returns a model and first one the valueQuerySet.

Comment: filter should only return one model, values() is my attempt to extract the values from the individual columns of the record (specifically whenToRun).  Is there another way to do this?  I have checked this code over and over again I don't believe that there are any misspellings.

Comment: `get` is the way to get only ONE model, then, you don't need to append `[0]` as @karthikr purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
timeToRun = Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i]).values()[0]['whenToRun'].split(' ')[0]
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields) `values()` is a `ValueQuerySet` (a list of queryset objects)

Now, if `Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i])` returns empty queryset, it would throw an error, so I would do:

```
if Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i]).exists(): #a quick lookup
    timeToRun = Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i]).values()[0]['whenToRun'].split(' ')[0]
```

One more level of optimization:

```
if Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i]).exists(): #a quick lookup
    timeToRun = list(Job.objects.filter(id=jobIDs[i]).values_list('whenToRun', flat=True))[0].split(' ')[0]
```